# Схема предложения с бессоюзной и сочинительной связью

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Нужно составить схему этого предложения: Везде всё было бело-бело и подвижно: то горизонт кажется необъятно-далёким, то сжатым на два шага во все стороны, то вдруг белая высокая стена вырастает справа и бежит вдоль саней, то вдруг исчезает...
Никак не могу понять, после двоеточия ещё 4 части или 2? Имею в виду, "то горизонт кажется необъятно-далёким, то сжатым на два шага во все стороны" - это одна часть или или две? Буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Везде всё было бело-бело и подвижно: то горизонт кажется необъятно-далёким, то сжатым на два шага во все стороны, то вдруг белая высокая стена вырастает справа и бежит вдоль саней, то вдруг исчезает.

[- = и =]:[то О, то О], [то О и О, то О].